# Autofac - Retrieving new instance of UnitOfWork - "DBcontext has been disposed error"

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, autofac

I have a batch job which is parsing a CSV file and creating and processing records. At each row, I have to perform commits as I need to create entities and then use the results of the created entities.

As there is thousands of records, the performance is slow and I am trying to improve my performance.

I have code which looks something like this:

```
var data = ParseExcel(filePath);
Setup();

foreach (var batch in data.Split(20))
{
    foreach (var row in batch)
    {
        try
        {
            ParseRow(row);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            JobLogger.Error(e, "Failed to parse row. Exception: " + e.Message);
            throw;
        }
    }

    _unitOfWork.Commit();
    _unitOfWork.Dispose();
    _unitOfWork = LifetimeScope.Resolve<Owned<IUnitOfWork>>().Value;
    ClientRepository = LifetimeScope.Resolve<Owned<IEntityBaseRepository<Client>>>().Value;
```

My Dispose method looks like this:

```
public void Dispose()
{
    _dbContext.Dispose();
    _dbContext = null;
    _dbFactory.Dispose();
    _dbFactory = null;
    GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
}
```

The intention here is that after each batch of records is processed, I want to refresh the unit of work by disposing of it and requesting that Autofac generates a new instance of it.

However, at the moment when I'm adding an item to my ClientRepository, it falls over with an error:

> The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been
>   disposed.

My ClientRepository is using a generic repository class which looks like this:

```
public class EntityBaseRepository<T> : IEntityBaseRepository<T> where T : class, IEntityBase, new()
    {
        private DataContext _dataContext;

        #region Properties
        protected IDbFactory DbFactory
        {
            get;
        }

        protected DataContext DbContext => _dataContext ?? (_dataContext = DbFactory.Initialise());

        public EntityBaseRepository(IDbFactory dbFactory)
        {
            DbFactory = dbFactory;
        }

        #endregion
```

Here is part of my UnitOfWork:

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork, IDisposable
{
    private IDbFactory _dbFactory;
    private DataContext _dbContext;

    public UnitOfWork(IDbFactory dbFactory)
    {
        _dbFactory = dbFactory;
    }

    public DataContext DbContext => _dbContext ?? (_dbContext = _dbFactory.Initialise());

    public void Commit()
    {
        DbContext.Commit();
    }
```

Any thoughts on why I am still getting this error?

Comment: Please post the code rather than screenshots

Comment: Updated with code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To ensure I get a fresh instance of my UnitOfWork after each batch of operations, I retrieve a reference to my current Autofac lifetime scope and ask Autofac to give me a new lifetime scope inside a using statement, then I use Autofac to register and resolve those dependencies. Some of my services also depend on the UnitOfWork so it was important that I get fresh instances of those dependencies too.

Here's a cut-down snippet:

```
foreach (var batch in data.Split(10))
{
    using (var scope = LifetimeScope.BeginLifetimeScope("UnitOfWork", b =>
    {
        b.RegisterType<UnitOfWork>().AsImplementedInterfaces().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
        b.RegisterType<MyService>().AsImplementedInterfaces().PropertiesAutowired().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
        b.RegisterGeneric(typeof(EntityBaseRepository<>)).As(typeof(IEntityBaseRepository<>)).InstancePerLifetimeScope();
    }))
    {
        UnitOfWork = scope.Resolve<IUnitOfWork>();
        MyService = scope.Resolve<IMyService>();

        foreach (var row in batch)
        {
            try
            {
                ParseRow(row);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                JobLogger.Error(e, "Failed to parse row. Exception: " + e.Message);
                throw;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

In the above code, I gave the name 'UnitOfWork' to the nested lifetime scope.

With this code in place, the performance of the job dramatically improved as this time I was not reusing the same UnitOfWork instance which was tracking tens of thousands of changes as it processed the file.

Additionally, I stopped splitting the data into batches of 10 - I decided to retrieve a new UnitOfWork after processing each row instead as each row already involved inserting data into at least 10 different tables.